# Converting string time to day timestamp

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have just started working for Pyspark, and need some help converting a column datatype. 
My dataframe has a string column, which stores the time of day in AM/PM, and I need to convert this into datetime for further processing/analysis.

```
fd = spark.createDataFrame([(['0143A'])], ['dt'])
fd.show()

+-----+
|   dt|
+-----+
|0143A|
+-----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, to_timestamp
#fd.select(date_format('dt','hhmma')).show()
fd.select(to_timestamp('dt','hhmmaa')).show()

+----------------------------+
|to_timestamp(`dt`, 'hhmmaa')|
+----------------------------+
|                        null|
+----------------------------+

Expected output: 01:43
```

How can I get the proper datetime format in the above scenario?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the doc for `to_timestamp` (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp) we see that the format must be specified as a SimpleDateFormat (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

In order to retrieve the time of the day in AM/PM, we must use `hhmma`. But in SimpleDateFormat, `a` catches `AM` or `PM`, and not `A` or `P`. So we need to change our string :

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
df = spark.createDataFrame([(['0143A'])], ['dt'])
df2 = df.withColumn('dt', F.concat(F.col('dt'), F.lit('M')))
df3 = df2.withColumn('ts', F.to_timestamp('dt','hhmma'))
df3.show()

+------+-------------------+
|    dt|                 ts|
+------+-------------------+
|0143AM|1970-01-01 01:43:00|
+------+-------------------+
```

If you want to retrieve it as a string in the format you mentionned, you can use `date_format` :

```python
df4 = df3.withColumn('time', F.date_format(F.col('ts'), format='HH:mm'))
df4.show()

+------+-------------------+-----+
|    dt|                 ts| time|
+------+-------------------+-----+
|0143AM|1970-01-01 01:43:00|01:43|
+------+-------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to process it further based on your suggestions.